# JSON Structure Types Naming Conventions

Tags: json, naming

I'm seeing JSON presented in a couple of different formats/styles, and I'm wondering if there are any **standard names** for these different formats/styles.
My searches haven't turned up any info - I'd appreciate anything anyone could share.

**Format 1:**

```
{
    "KEYS": ["first", "last", "middle", "age"],
    "VALUES": [
        ["joe", "smith", "a", 34],
        ["mary", "morris", "p", 65],
        ["phillip", "jones", "a", 33]
    ]
}
```

**Format 2:**

```
[{
    "first": "joe",
    "last": "smith",
    "middle": "a",
    "age": 34
}, {
    "first": "mary",
    "last": "morris",
    "middle": "p",
    "age": 33
}, {
    "first": "phillip",
    "last": "jones",
    "middle": "a",
    "age": 33
}]
```

Comment: Sublime formats JSON like the first section and Sublime rules, so therefore the first statement wins. :)

Comment: I'm more talking about the arrangement of data as an array of keys and arrays of values vs. sets of key/value pairs.

Comment: Ah gotcha. I think this is use case dependent since you would have to look into what is rendering the JSON. Look into if it is more expensive/usable to create an object vs having mirrored arrays. I prefer objects but that is just me.

Comment: Thanks - I understand the merits of each structure, just wondering if each structure has a commonly used name to refer to it.

Answer (score 1):

A colleague suggested "tabular" for format 1 (I also like "mirrored arrays") and "standard" for format 2. Unless someone knows of some more formal/common names, I'll stick with these for now.

Answer (score 0):

The first JSON structure is more suitable for table representation while the second is a classic JSON representation of a list of objects.

Comment: Gotcha - are you aware of any commonly used names for these structures?

Answer (score 0):

The second format seems much more standard, as it's using key-value pairs the way JSON intends. It's the [format produced by d3.dsv](https://tonicdev.com/stevage/56e24b9792cd3f1100b396db) for instance.

It's a bit hard to be definitive though.

Comment: Thanks - just wondering if each structure has a commonly used name to refer to it.